# How to tell the code running in Spark is more efficient

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I'm new in Spark to do big data works, and I'm using a cluster which is shared with others, therefore, at different time, when I am running different code I cannot tell which code is more efficient just based on the running time, because someone else maybe running some huge data works.

Is there anyway in Spark python to judge whether the code is efficient or not?

Comment: It's called benchmarking and experience. You'll need to read the documentation and decided what suits your application the most. There is not such thing in Spark.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way you can make this kind of inference from Spark itself, because your application context doesn't know whether it's running concurrently with other ones or not.

*Maybe* if your application is shuffling a lot of data, you can make guesses by observing variations in the amount of time spent waiting for data. If you know the cluster's capacity, you might also be able to observe the number of executors that were allocated to your application (that might be more or less relevant depending on the master Spark is using).

What you would like is find a way to detect by yourself any other application.
I don't know if the master API does provide, or not, a method to do such things (which would be the better way to go, i.e request that indicator periodically while your application is running), but if you are on the same machine where the master is installed, you can play with `grep` and `ls -t $SPARK_HOME/logs/app*` to monitor the number of existing event logs (which is simple and might be worthwhile if you want a quick solution).